# reading text file from Amazon S3 with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, cloud

I am trying to get a Spark cluster to read data sources from Amazon S3 cloud storage. This results in the following error, for which I need some help diagnosing the problem:

```
>>> sc.textFile("s3a://storage-bucket/s3test.txt").collect()

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: D47397DA8BCB4669, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Bad Request, S3 Extended Request ID: /aBi99tozgFEsdRGubDwhriMsNQvl1jLOf8AJquA8VXxzkpPL/LLCWDFQQvYn4snHx5gx66/pXo=
```

This works fine by the way:

```
$ aws s3 cp s3://storage-bucket/s3test.txt ./s3text.txt
download: s3://storage-bucket/s3test.txt to ./s3text.txt
$ cat s3text.txt 
Hello S3
```

Some more detail from the error message:

```
Caused by: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: Service Error Message. -- ResponseCode: 403, ResponseStatus: Forbidden, XML Error Message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>SignatureDoe
sNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</AWSAccessKeyId><St
```

Comment: @RameshMaharjan the collect result? That didn't change anything, and the error message points to a problem on the S3 side.

Comment: can you post full error log?

Comment: To get a better debug can you try and access the file like this `aws s3 cp s3://storage-bucket/s3test.txt ./s3test.txt`

Comment: @destroy-everything good idea, but this works without problems

Comment: Can you try with `sc.parallelize([1,2,3]).collect()` to see if there's a problem with S3 or your Spark configuration?

Comment: Spark is working fine, it is a problem with S3.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your `fs.s3a.access.key` and `fs.s3a.secret.key` and make sure they match the same credentials that you used to perform the `aws s3 cp` test. This `SignatureDosNotMatch`error can show up when the credentials are wrong. try `hdfs fs -ls s3a://storage-bucket/`

Answer (score 1):

there is something up with your config. The S3A connector uses the AWS SDK. If your stack traces includes jets3t then your have somehow wired up the wrong filesystem to it. Remove from your source anythig which sets properties about fs.s3a.impl and rely on the Hadoop runtime to sort things out, then repeat

Comment: Could you translate that into something that's actionable for Spark beginners please? I am not aware of setting any properties, and I don't know whether I am relying on the Hadoop runtime or not.

Comment: OK. The fact that the stack trace has the line "org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException" means that whatever S3 connector it is is using, it is not the official ASF s3a connector. I was suggesting that the configuration is wrong, but the other possibility is you are using Amazon EMR, in which case you are using their closed source connector. Which is it?